# Warning in table exercise R-exams

Tags: warnings, r-exams

I used the template `fourfold.Rmd` to create an exercise of type cloze using a table to be filled by the student. This is my exercise:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
rm(list=ls())
p_load("tidyverse")
categs<-LETTERS[1:3]
ncat<-length(categs)
varname<-"Tr"

categ_ref<-sample(1:ncat,1)
if(categ_ref==1){
  sol<-c(0,1,0,
         0,0,1)
}else if(categ_ref==2){
  sol<-c(1,0,0,
         0,0,1)
}else if(categ_ref==3){
  sol<-c(1,0,0,
         0,1,0)
}
questions<-rep("",length(sol))
type<-rep("num",length(sol))
```
Question
========
Considere la variable tratamiento ($`r varname `$) con posibles valores $`r                 paste0(categs,collapse = ",")`$. Sean $I_{`r categs[1]`},I_{`r categs[2]`}$ e $I_{`r categs[3]`}$ variables indicadoras de los respectivos tratamientos. Llene la tabla para establecer un sistema de codificación para la variable tratamiento, en donde la categoría de referencia es el tratamiento $`r categs[categ_ref]`$ 

  | $`r varname `$| $I_{`r categs[-categ_ref][1]`}$|$I_{`r categs[-categ_ref][2]`}$                 | 
  |:-------------:|:-----------------:|:-----------------:|
  |$A$         | \#\#ANSWER1\#\# |\#\#ANSWER4\#\# |
  |$B$         | \#\#ANSWER2\#\# | \#\#ANSWER5\#\# |
  |$C$         | \#\#ANSWER3\#\# | \#\#ANSWER6\#\# |


```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(questions, markup = "markdown")
```
Solution
========
  
  | $`r varname `$| $I_{`r categs[-categ_ref][1]`}$|$I_{`r categs[-categ_ref][2]`}$| 
  |:-------------:|:-----------------:|:-----------------:|
  |$A$          | `r sol[1]`  |`r sol[4]`  |
  |$B$         | `r sol[2]`  | `r sol[5]`  |
  |$C$         | `r sol[3]`  | `r sol[6]`  |
  
  
Meta-information
================
extype: cloze
exsolution: `r paste(sol, collapse = "|")`
exclozetype: `r paste(type, collapse = "|")`
exname: catreg
extol: 0.05
exextra[numwidth,logical]: TRUE
````

rendering using `exams2html` or `exams2moodle` produces the following warning:

`Warning in split.default(exm[[j]]$questionlist, g) : data length is not a multiple of split variable`

I just can’t understand why is this appearing. I have similar version of this exercise and they don’t produce any warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a blank line after the answer list code chunk and before the start of the solution section. Otherwise the length of the answer list is not detected correctly.